# "Could not find RubyGem rails" on 10.7.1 Server

Tags: macos, rails

I just cannot get Rails to work on my 10.7.1 Server installation. After having run `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 gem install rails --force` as root, I still get this:

```
% rails
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
  from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

RVM doesn't appear to be producing a working install either.

To cap it all, this lack of Rails is preventing Profile Manager from running.

Does anybody know what could be going wrong here? I've tried a clean install of 10.7 (not Server, though) on another machine, and Rails runs fine in that. I'm not particularly keen on nuking and reinstalling my main system, though!

Comment: try upgrading rubygems or try uninstalling rails and installing using gem

gem update --system ; gem uninstall rails; gem install rails

Comment: Thanks — that seems to have fixed things. If you put that as an answer rather than a comment I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading rubygems or try uninstalling rails and installing back again using gems.

> ```
> gem update --system 
> gem uninstall rails
> gem install rails
> ```